# When is a topological space $X$ the disjoint union of orbits under a continuous $G$-action?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, homogeneous-spaces

For $G$ a topological group acting continuously on a space $X$, when can we write the space (topologically) as the disjoint union of orbits i.e., when is
$$
X\cong\coprod_{O\in X/G}O
$$
Further, for $x\in O$, when is the canonical bijection a homeomorphism
$$
O\cong G/\mathrm{Stab}\left(x\right)
$$
I am looking for the conditions on $X$ and $G$, as well as on the action.

Comment: As given in this answer, that doesn't seem to be the case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47239/totally-disconnected-orbit-stabilizer-theorem

Comment: Assume $G$ is Hausdorff, locally compact, and has a countable basis of open sets.  If $X$ is also Hausdorff, and the orbit $G.x$ is also locally compact, then the natural continuous bijection $G/G_x \rightarrow G.x$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: In this case, can $X$ be written as the disjoint union of its orbits?

Comment: Usually not.  That would only be the case when each orbit is both open and closed in $X$.  In general, the orbits are neither open nor closed.

Comment: @D_S it is ALWAYS a disjoint union of the orbits - this is a set-theoretic statement having nothing to do with topology.

Comment: @IgorRivin OP probably means to ask when that disjoint union has the disjoint union topology. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)

Comment: @D_S yes, that is what I mean. So there must be some conditions on the action saying when the orbits are both open and closed.

Comment: open and closed -> each orbit is a union of connected components of $X.$ Not what one would describe as an. interesting situation.

Comment: I suggest you read about the Slice Theorem, which is the best general result about the local structure of group actions https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Slice_theorem